# JavaScript Input Based Background Change?

Tags: javascript

My function used to work, but now it won't. I'm trying to add an if statement for when the input is left blank, it returns to the default background color.

```
var path = /^([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$/g;

function col(obj) {
    var val = obj.value;
    if (path.test(val)) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + val;
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('bgcol').onkeyup = function () {
        col(this);
    }
    if (getElementById('bgcol'.value = null || ""){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
}
}
```

//end javascript, begin html below

```
 <input id="bgcol" placeholder="enter hexadecimal color"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hWBLQ/)

```
if (getElementById('bgcol').value == "") {
```

and

```
document.getElementById('bgcol').onkeyup = function () {
    if (this.value == ""){
       document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
    }
    else {
       col(this);
    }
}
```

and

```
<input id="bgcol" placeholder="enter hexadecimal color" />
```

Comment: @Kolink yeah i got it, my mistake was that `||` OR gate was not used as it should be.

Comment: @Kolink fixed it, now see it :D

Answer (score 0):

You need `document.getElementById` and to clean up your syntax:

```
if ( document.getElementById('bgcol').value == null || document.getElementById('bgcol').value == "")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this simplified version of your code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('bgcol').onkeyup = function() {
        var col = this.value;
        if( !col.match(/^#?(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}$/i)) col = "#000000";
        if( col.charAt(0) != "#") col = "#"+col;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = col;
    };
};
```

It uses a simpler regex and also allows the `#` to be accepted and optional.